# Windows store app - XAML - One style with different images

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I've been looking at a [blog](http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Windows-8-XAML-Metro-Apps-with-OData-Part-2.aspx) that contains some info about having styles for app bar buttons. Below is one of the styles i edited slightly.

```xml
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="TasksButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="White" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Ellipse.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonEllipse" />
                                            <ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Glyph" />
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Grid  Margin="0,14,0,5" >
                                    <Ellipse x:Name="ButtonEllipse" Height="40" Width="40" Fill="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          Stroke="#FF00A5E7" StrokeThickness="2" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                    <Image x:Name="ButtonImage" Source="/Assets/Image1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                                </Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                        FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="12"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
```

I want to use this style many times though I'm unsure if there is way I can change the image source of this line

```xml
<Image Source="/Assets/Image1.png" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

without simply just copying a pasting the entire style.

I want to do something like this. (I've tried it but it doesn't appear to be valid)

Pseudo XAML

```xml
<Button x:Uid="appbarOne" Click="NavButton_Click" Tag="Client.Pages.one" Style="{StaticResource TasksButtonStyle ButtonImage.Source="Assets/Image1"}" Content="Tasks"/>
<Button x:Uid="appbarTwo" Click="NavButton_Click" Tag="Client.Pages.two" Style="{StaticResource TasksButtonStyle ButtonImage.Source="Assets/Image2"}" Content="Tasks"/>
<Button x:Uid="appbarThree" Click="NavButton_Click" Tag="Client.Pages.three" Style="{StaticResource TasksButtonStyle ButtonImage.Source="Assets/Image3"}" Content="Tasks"/>
<Button x:Uid="appbarFour" Click="NavButton_Click" Tag="Client.Pages.four" Style="{StaticResource TasksButtonStyle ButtonImage.Source="Assets/Image4"}" Content="Tasks"/>
```

Is there a way i can do this using something similar to `Style="{StaticResource TasksButtonStyle ButtonImage.Source="Assets/Image4"}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `<Image />` in custom style with this.

```xml
<Image x:Name="ButtonImage" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Stretch="None"
       Source="{Binding Path=(local:AppBarButton.Image),RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
```

Remove below line from style as there is no element named "Glyph"

```xml
<ColorAnimation Duration="0" To="Black" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Foreground).(SolidColorBrush.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="Glyph" />
```

Add a class named `AppBarButton` with below given definition. It has one attached property `Image`. We will use that to provide image source from button tag to button style.

```csharp
public class AppBarButton
{
    public static string GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (string)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, string value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image", typeof(string), typeof(AppBarButton), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));
}
```

Now in you XAML page add buttons like this,

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TasksButtonStyle}" local:AppBarButton.Image="ms-appx:///Assets/Screenshot_2.png" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TasksButtonStyle}" local:AppBarButton.Image="ms-appx:///Assets/Screenshot_3.png" />
    <Button Style="{StaticResource TasksButtonStyle}" local:AppBarButton.Image="ms-appx:///Assets/Screenshot_4.png" />
</StackPanel>
```

Here `local` refers to namespace of class `AppBarButton`. For my case it's

```xml
<Page
    x:Class="App2.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App2"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Because I declared `AppBarButton` class in `App2` namespace.

Comment: Will give this a try. I notice the Glyph problem myself, I think the `<TextBlock />` element should be named `Glyph` in the original example I copied it from in the blog. Good spot though!

Comment: Of course! I've got my `MyAppBarButton` class in my `Common` namespace and I'm getting `The namespace prefix MyApp.Common is not defined` error on my line containing `MyApp.Common:MyAppBarButton.Image="ms-appx:///Assets/blue_32_clipboard.png"`. Any idea's what i may be missing?

Comment: You have to define `xmlns:common="using:MyApp.Common"` in `<Page ... />`

Comment: Now I'm getting a runtime error of `Failed to assign to property 'MyApp.Common.MyAppBarButton.Image'. [Line: 63 Position: 175]` Line 63 includes: `common:MyAppBarButton.Image="ms-appx:///Assets/blue_32_clipboard.png"`. Any idea's?

Comment: Please make sure you have followed my solution correctly, especially in `AppBarButton` class & style of button.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51813/discussion-between-ne0-and-xyroid)

Comment: [CHAT](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51813/discussion-between-ne0-and-xyroid)

Answer (score 0):

you can use put the styles in a new xaml file say globalstyles.xaml.
then refer the xaml file in you page as below,

```
 <UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary  Source="../Styles.xaml"></ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

once the styles have been referred in the Page you can use the style as below

```
<Button Name="cancel" Content="cancel" Style="{StaticResource CancelButtonStyle}" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,45,5,7" />

<Button Name="Submit" Content="Submit" Style="{StaticResource SubmitButtonStyle}" 
                   HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="5,45,5,7" />
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a template that will use an attached property. In code, add a new class for the attached property:

```
public class AssociatedObject
{
    public static ImageSource GetImage(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (ImageSource)obj.GetValue(ImageProperty);
    }

    public static void SetImage(DependencyObject obj, ImageSource value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ImageProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Image.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(AssociatedObject), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

Then, in your template, do a `TemplateBinding` to the parent object (removing most of the style for brevity):

```
    <Style x:Key="ButtonStyle1" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
  // REMOVED A BUNCH HERE
                         <Border x:Name="Border" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="3">
                            <Grid>
  // YOUR IMAGE IS HERE
                                <Image Source="{TemplateBinding local:AssociatedObject.Image}" Stretch="None"/>
                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter" AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                           </Grid>
                        </Border>
               </ControlTemplate>
 // REMOVED A BUNCH HERE
             </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Look at the **`Image`** element in the `Grid`. It contains a TemplateBinding to the parent. Then, when you instantiate your button in XAML, you simply need to say what the `AssociatedObject.Image` is set to:

```
    <Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle1}" local:AssociatedObject.Image="/assets/Logo.scale-100.png"></Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the look of an appbar button, you should look at the AppBarButton class instead which has everything for you.  You can then use the Icon property to use one of the 200+ built-in icon styles or provide your own through the PathIcon, SymbolIcon or BitmapIcon classes as well.

See: http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2013/10/29/use-new-appbarbutton-in-windows-8-1-commandbar.aspx